# Wordpress post date before title

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new with WordPress, so my question is : is there any way, by entering and modifying a script or maybe something from its post settings, to get the post date right before the title.
I looked up all other threads about similar issues and could not manage to solve the problem. I kind of need a step by step guide. Thanks in advance and sorry for the inconvenience.

Post list I'm trying to edit

[image]

Comment: You can do this with your file.

Comment: And by file you mean...which/what file?

Comment: Is this a default post listing page?

Comment: Hey @user3069396, try asking here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KrupalPanchal No. It is a side list where we post all newsflash articles. It is situated on the main page. You can take a look https://adrvest.ro/.

Comment: @BossElijah Thank you. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin [WP Date and Time Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-date-and-time-shortcode/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to do the above -

```
function insert_date_before_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    if( get_post_type( $post ) == 'post' ) { // allow for post title only
        $title = get_the_date( $post ) . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'insert_date_before_title', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ill try this!

Comment: This is a working code. First of all tell me how you call the post title in the above page image. You should call the post title using the_title().